# Difference between template specialization and SFINAE with std::enable_if?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, enable-if

If I have a template function in C++, and want it to behave in a different manner in presence of a specific template parameter, I will use a template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void myFunction(T&& input) {
    std::cout << "The parameter is " << input << '\n';
}

template<> void myFunction<int>(int&& input) {
    std::cout << "Double of the parameter is " << 2 * input << '\n';
}

int main() {
    myFunction(24.2);
    myFunction(24);
    myFunction("Hello");
}
```

Use of `std::enable_if<bool B>` from `<type_traits>` enables to activate a similar behaviour for some specific template types. Any other type would cause a substitution error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr > 
void myFunction(T&& input) {
    std::cout << "Double of the parameter is " << 2 * input << '\n';
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr > 
void myFunction(T&& input) {
    std::cout << "The parameter is " << input << '\n';
}

int main() {
    myFunction(24.2);
    myFunction(24);
    // myFunction("Hello"); // compile-time substitution error
}
```

My question is: what is really the gain of using the fancier `std::enable_if` specialization, in place of the standard template specialization?
Are they really alternatives, or `std::enable_if` is exclusively for template metaprogramming?

Comment: i dont understand the question, in the first version the overload is for `int`. In the second case the overlaod is for any `T` with `std::is_floating_point_v<T> == true`. How would you do that without `std::enable_if` ?

Comment: you can use enable_if to have a specialization for "any integer type" rather than just int, for instance, as your example already shows. Or really for any condition you can think of. I don't see the confusion TBH

Comment: "Are they really alternatives" no, the two codes do very different things.

Comment: @CássioRenan it's difficult to make `enable_if` select only for `string` for instance. I cannot see anything of the kind in `<type_traits>`.

Comment: C++20 has concept and constraint which superseeds `std::enable_if`.

Comment: "t's difficult to make enable_if select only string for instance" not at all. `std::enable_if< std::is_same_v<T,std::string>, ...`

Comment: `enable_if` allows overloads to be eligible based on complex predicates. Specialization only allows you to define different behaviors for exact types. But with *partial* template specializations and helper structs, you can achieve similar behavior.

Comment: i mean you can replace the overload in the first case with something that uses `std::enable_if`. What I find confusing about the question is that the two version you posted are soo different in what they do that I don't see how comparing how they do it makes sense

Comment: _"it's difficult to make enable_if select only string for instance"_.  That would look like `std::enable_if< std::is_same_v<T,std::string>>`, although you could simply make a non-template overload.  Depending on wheher you are specializing for "exactly string" or "convertible to string".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for the `type_trait` for `string`.

Comment: If you want to match an exact type like `std::string`, just define an non-template overload. The compiler will prefer that one to the template. This of course assumes you're always deducing the template parameters...

Comment: the fact that specializing for a single type (e.g.: std::string) is more verbose is not the point. There seems to be a premise, or a false dichotomy here, where you can only use one of the "two options" in your entire codebase. This premise is false. Use template specialization if it's clearer, use enable_if (or concepts on more modern code) if you need more complex predicates.

Comment: @Jarod42 and FrançoisAndrieux sound promising, I'll look into these new features

Comment: if you specialize you need a specialization for each integer type.  using SFINAE you only need one overload for all integer types.

Comment: @Giogre, SFINAE-ing out overloads also helps making errors more readable. I've given an example of it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 approaches are executed on different stages.
First is overload resolution - on this stage template specialization is not used. Only generic template function prototype is in use.

On the other hand SFINAE approach drops the overloads that failed to be substituted silently on this stage leaving only one candidate based on enable_if conditions.

Second step is template instantiation - here the body of your function is created - and it will use body provided by most specialized template.

Comment: I understand, any of he two approaches produce the same machine code for execution. SFINAE does not offer a generic prototype to fall back on in case the type handled does not satisfy the `enable_if`s. Which of the two approaches would be faster to compile?

Comment: I do not think you will see any significant difference in performance - but template specialization probably does OR step a little bit easier - so it may be quicker in case when you have a lot of specializations/SFINAE cases to cover

Answer (score 1):

With `std::enable_if<>`, you can write arbitrary conditions. An example is specializing based on the size of the object; other examples include whether a field / member function exists, whether the result of a `static constexpr` function is what's expected. Specialization is limited to the type matching.

Comment: So to use `enable_if` as a hack for template specialization is very narrow as it is a much more versatile concept.
Also on the other hand `enable_if` lacks the generic prototype offered by the template function. Only the types allowed by `enable_if` can be used.

Comment: @Giogre Wouldn't say it's very narrow - it's certainly template metaprogramming though. What do you mean on 'types allowed by enable_if'? As far as I understand, any type can be used with `enable_if`.

Comment: I agree with you. To clarify, with 'types allowed by `enable_if`' I banally meant the ones used as parameters of `enable_if`. They vary depending on the code at hand. In my example above I used integrals and floating_point types for `enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

SFINAE also helps misuse of template entities result in more readable errors.

**A bit longer**

Not using SFINAE but just relying on specializations means, among other things, that you are leaving an unrestrained primary template available for overload resolution, which can result in very lengthly, and not easily readable errors, if it gets fed with types which the implementation doesn't make sense.

Indeed, the template will always be instantiated thanks to template type deduction, but then, if the type doesn't happen to be suitable for the implementation of that function. That will be discovered maybe deep in several nested function calls.

As noted in another answer, SFINAE allows one to discard some overloads (SFINAE them out, somebody says) before overload resolution actually takes place, hopefully leaving much less overloads standing, for the benefit of programmer who will read shorter errors.

---

**Example**

This is a (not too far from) real-life example of how template errors can be long, but made shorter thanks to SFINAE.

In the toy example below, I've defined a template function for inserting an element in a collection.
A few details to better understand why I wrote it the way I did:

- The insertions of an element in a `std::unordered_set<T, whatever>` requires that `operator==` is defined on two arguments of type `T`; as you can see from the commented `friend` function, I've intentionally not defined it for the type `A`, so as to make the code fail at compile time (if you uncomment that line the code compiles and runs smoothly).

  - You can disregard the silly hash function; it's there just to make the code compile in case you uncomment the `friend` definition.
- I've defined an `Equatable` concept to check whether `operator==` is defined on two arguments of a given type `T`, i.e. if the type is suitable for the element type of an `unordered_set`; this was to have a predicate to apply to a type as the condition for an `enable_if`.
- `myInsert` is the function object of the question, a template function which is unrestricted.

  - You can also imagine you've written a specialization for another class `B` on which `operator==` *is* defined, but the point is that among all other types you can throw at it, there's `A`, on which `operator==` *is not* defined, and *this* is causing the error.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_set>

// concept to detect whether operator== is defined argument of a type T
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Equatable : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct Equatable<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{} == T{})>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T>
constexpr bool equatable_v = Equatable<T>::value;

// The problematic class which has no operator== defined on it
struct A {
    void empty(int) {
    }
    //friend bool operator==(A const&, A const&) { return true; }
};

// Our template function not using SFINAE
template<typename Coll, typename Elem>
void myInsert(Coll& coll, Elem&& elem) {
    coll.insert(std::move(elem));
}

int main() {
    auto hash = [](A const&){ return 1; };
    std::unordered_set<A, decltype(hash)> s;
    myInsert(s, A{});
}
```

Try to compile the code above. You'll most likely get an error which is long with respect to compile-time errors of non-templated code (but believe me, it's short! I've actually included `<cmath>` for the purpose of triggering more instantiation attempts to make the error a bit longer). Here's what I get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/unordered_set:44,
                 from example.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool std::equal_to<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A]’:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1701:18:   required from ‘bool std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _Traits>::_M_key_equals_tr(const _Kt&, const std::__detail::_Hash_node_value<_Value, typename _Traits::__hash_cached::value>&) const [with _Kt = A; _Key = A; _Value = A; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<A>; _Hash = main()::<lambda(const A&)>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>; typename _Traits::__hash_cached = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>::__hash_cached]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:2237:32:   required from ‘std::pair<typename std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator, bool> std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_M_insert_unique(_Kt&&, _Arg&&, const _NodeGenerator&) [with _Kt = A; _Arg = A; _NodeGenerator = std::__detail::_AllocNode<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<A, true> > >; _Key = A; _Value = A; _Alloc = std::allocator<A>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<A>; _Hash = main()::<lambda(const A&)>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>; typename std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator = std::__detail::_Insert_base<A, A, std::allocator<A>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<A>, main()::<lambda(const A&)>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >::iterator; typename _Traits::__constant_iterators = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>::__constant_iterators]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:906:27:   required from ‘std::pair<typename std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator, bool> std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_M_insert(_Arg&&, const _NodeGenerator&, std::true_type) [with _Arg = A; _NodeGenerator = std::__detail::_AllocNode<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<A, true> > >; _Key = A; _Value = A; _Alloc = std::allocator<A>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<A>; _Hash = main()::<lambda(const A&)>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>; typename std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::iterator = std::__detail::_Insert_base<A, A, std::allocator<A>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<A>, main()::<lambda(const A&)>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >::iterator; typename _Traits::__constant_iterators = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>::__constant_iterators; std::true_type = std::integral_constant<bool, true>]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1035:22:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::__ireturn_type std::__detail::_Insert<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _Hash, _RangeHash, _Unused, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::insert(value_type&&) [with _Key = A; _Value = A; _Alloc = std::allocator<A>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<A>; _Hash = main()::<lambda(const A&)>; _RangeHash = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Unused = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>; __ireturn_type = std::__detail::_Insert<A, A, std::allocator<A>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<A>, main()::<lambda(const A&)>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>, true>::__ireturn_type; value_type = A]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/unordered_set.h:426:27:   required from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Hashtable<_Value, _Value, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Identity, _Pred, _Hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<_Hash>, std::__is_nothrow_invocable<const _Hash&, const _Tp&> > >::value, true, true> >::iterator, bool> std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::insert(value_type&&) [with _Value = A; _Hash = main()::<lambda(const A&)>; _Pred = std::equal_to<A>; _Alloc = std::allocator<A>; typename std::_Hashtable<_Value, _Value, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Identity, _Pred, _Hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<_Hash>, std::__is_nothrow_invocable<const _Hash&, const _Tp&> > >::value, true, true> >::iterator = std::__detail::_Insert_base<A, A, std::allocator<A>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<A>, main()::<lambda(const A&)>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >::iterator; value_type = A]’
example.cpp:28:16:   required from ‘void myInsert(Coll&, Elem&&) [with Coll = std::unordered_set<A, main()::<lambda(const A&)> >; Elem = A]’
example.cpp:34:13:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const A’ and ‘const A’)
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/specfun.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/cmath:1935,
                 from example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:530:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&) requires requires{{std::operator==::__x->base() == std::operator==::__y->base()} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::convertible_to<<placeholder>, bool>];}’ (reversed)
  530 |     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:530:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>’
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1656:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const move_iterator<_IteratorR>&) requires requires{{std::operator==::__x->base() == std::operator==::__y->base()} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::convertible_to<<placeholder>, bool>];}’ (reversed)
 1656 |     operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1656:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/unordered_set:40:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/allocator.h:219:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const allocator<_Up>&, const allocator<_T2>&)’ (reversed)
  219 |     operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/allocator.h:219:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_Up>’
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:640:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>&, const pair<_T1, _T2>&)’
  640 |     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:640:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:589:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&) requires requires{{std::operator==::__x->base() == std::operator==::__y->base()} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::convertible_to<<placeholder>, bool>];}’
  589 |     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:589:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>’
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1726:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)’
 1726 |     operator==(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1726:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:378:20: note:   ‘const A’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
  378 |       { return __x == __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
```

I challenge you to read it and tell me it's easy to understand what's telling us.

What's the alternative? Using `std::enable_if` to enforce the condition that the types fed to `myInsert` have to satisfy. A simplified and incomplete attempt consists in changing the line

```cpp
template<typename Coll, typename Elem>
```

to

```cpp
template<typename Coll, typename Elem, std::enable_if_t<equatable_v<Elem>> = 0>
```

which results in the error to become much shorter:

```cpp
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:34:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘myInsert(std::unordered_set<A, main()::<lambda(const A&)> >&, A)’
   34 |     myInsert(s, A{});
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
example.cpp:27:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Coll, class Elem, typename std::enable_if<equatable_v<Elem>, int>::type <anonymous> > void myInsert(Coll&, Elem&&)’
   27 | void myInsert(Coll& coll, Elem&& elem) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~
example.cpp:27:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
example.cpp:23:46: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, int>’
   23 | , std::enable_if_t<equatable_v<Elem>, int> = 0>
      |                                              ^
```

Comment: SFINAE as "error-verbosity prevention", never thought about it under this angle. Great example and exhaustive explanation.